# How to add MenuItem to SubMenu in Google's new NavigationView?

Tags: android, navigationview

I have made an xml for my drawer menu which contains the following MenuItem:

```
<item android:title="Contacts"
    android:id="@+id/contact_list">
  <menu>

  </menu>
</item>
```

In my MainActivity I get a reference to the empty SubMenu and try to add a new test MenuItem to the the SubMenu.

```
mNavMenu = mNavigationView.getMenu();
mNavMenu.findItem(R.id.contact_list).getSubMenu().add("hello");
```

Unfortunately, this is not working and the MenuItems are not being added. I have tried many other different variations of this but none of them update the SubMenu in my navigation drawer.

Could this possibly be a bug?

Comment: as far as I know this is a bug in the library, but I didn't find a reference for it yet

Answer (score 1):

So apparently, the only solution right now is to use reflection to call notifyDataSetChanged() on the menu:

```
    for (int j = 0, count = mNavigationView.getChildCount(); j < count; j++) {
      final View child = mNavigationView.getChildAt(j);
      if (child != null && child instanceof ListView) {
        final ListView menuView = (ListView) child;
        final HeaderViewListAdapter adapter = (HeaderViewListAdapter) menuView.getAdapter();
        final BaseAdapter wrapped = (BaseAdapter) adapter.getWrappedAdapter();
        wrapped.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
     }
```

This will update the menu with your new items.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in wrong way...
You don't have to find the menu agian ... just call the method on the instance of **mNavMenu** ..

```
 mNavMenu = mNavigationView.getMenu();
 mNavMenu.addSubMenu("It's new bro .. ");
```

Comment: The above works and does in fact create a new submenu but I am having problems adding menu items into an existing submenu. I was already successful in creating a submenu. The issue is adding menu items to the submenu itself once it has been created, either in the layout or programmatically in code like you showed here.