# Programmatically refresh Android Design Support NavigationView

Tags: android, navigationview, android-navigationview

So, in my main activity, I have a NavigationView set up which includes a total of two submenus, one titled "My Projects" and another titled "Shared Projects." I have it set so that when the activity is created, it fetches the projects from my server and adds it to the drawer in this manner:

```
    Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
    Menu myProjects = menu.findItem(R.id.myProjects).getSubMenu();
    Menu sharedProjects = menu.findItem(R.id.sharedProjects).getSubMenu();

    for (int i = 0; i < myProjectList.size(); i++) {
        myProjects.add(myProjectList.get(i).getTitle()).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<sharedProjectList.size(); i++) {
        sharedProjects.add(sharedProjectList.get(i).getTitle()).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp);
    }

    MenuItem mi = menu.getItem(menu.size() - 1);
    mi.setTitle(mi.getTitle());
```

This works just fine, and gives me the output I was looking for. However, I would like to extend this functionality to a point where if the user creates a new project in the app, it should update it within the drawer without having to restart the entire activity. The android developer documentation doesn't highlight any method such as a notifyDataSetChanged() or the sorts which would allow refreshing the view.

As for my data, it is organized in two arrayLists, myProjectList and sharedProjectList. The List is composed of project objects which are publicly accessible throughout the activity and asynchronously updated with any changes made by the user.

**EDIT2: SOLVED** It seems as if someone has a similar answer posted at this question:

[How to add MenuItem to SubMenu in Google's new NavigationView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690228/how-to-add-menuitem-to-submenu-in-googles-new-navigationview?rq=1)

Adding this to onResume and updating my original list works perfectly:

```
final View child = navigationView.getChildAt(0);
                if (child != null && child instanceof ListView) {
                    final ListView menuView = (ListView) child;
                    final HeaderViewListAdapter adapter = (HeaderViewListAdapter) menuView.getAdapter();
                    final BaseAdapter wrapped = (BaseAdapter) adapter.getWrappedAdapter();
                    wrapped.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
```

Comment: Did you try using `navigationView.invalidate()`?

Comment: no, but it's alright it seems as if the answer in the second stack overflow question I posted was actually asking the adapter to refresh the content. The only reason it kept making duplicates of the other elements is because I didn't realize that I kept calling on the function that recreated the drawer. Thanks though!